# WordPress v3.1 Has Character Encoding Issue With Title/Permalink?

Tags: slug, encoding

I was on the latest v3.0.x series and had no issues. Once I upgraded to WP v3.1, I am having a strange issue with character encoding in permalinks.

If my title was "I have $50 today" in WP 3.0.x, the month/date permalink would be

```
example.com/2010/05/i-have-50-today/
```

However, here's what is happening in WP 3.1

```
example.com/2010/05/i-have-%e2%80%93-50-today/
```

I tried replicating the problem on a clean install of WordPress and was able to replicate the same issue. Can anyone confirm whether this is a bug or expected?

Comment: In my installation of 3.1, the permalink ends up as `example.com/2010/05/i-have-50-today/`, so you must be doing something different.

Comment: Hmm, happened on two different installations too. I have W3TC running, but I don't knower of that is the cause. Omge was a fresh install too.

Comment: Are you sure it was a regular dollar-sign character? Did you type it in normally, or did you cut-and-paste it from someplace else?

Comment: Hey Doug, it looks like it was the '-' symbol causing the issue. Here's the article in question: http://skattertech.com/2011/02/giveaway-clearwire-rover-puck-4g-mobile-hotspot-%E2%80%93-150-value/ Is there a way to change the permalink after publishing? The edit slug button doesn't let me change it. It goes back to how it is now even once I save.

Comment: Never mind, I resolved the issue. Sorry for the trouble. Dougal, you were right about the wrong character. It looked exactly like a dash but somehow one of them was wrong.

Comment: @Sahas If this issue is resolved, could you either close the question or post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted so that this doesn't sit in the 'Unanswered' category?

Comment: I do not see a close question button anywhere. How do I do that?

Comment: Please add it as answer and mark it as solution later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The permalink slug under the title of a new post would not let me tweak the slug for some reason. I was able to get rid of the unwanted '-' in the permalink by heading to the posts list and clicking quick edit to edit the slug over there.